# New card shows images from previous card after swipe

Tags: ionic-framework

After swiping (as demonstrated in the video below) the images from the previous card flash for a little bit, which is pretty annoying and looks ugly as hell. Any suggestions/ideas to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Example video (because it's the only way to explain the problem)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44fFZrU83qk

Comment: Chances are that the images are being updated after the animation is complete. Share your code.

Comment: @Constant http://pastebin.com/Pz1EriZC

Comment: i can't see any flashing! Looks perfect to me!

Comment: can you please add the followign code : HTML of your page & Your controller Or Service taht iniate datas. If it's a service, show us where you update your Controller datas. PS. I do see the image flash again.

Comment: @aorfevre HTML: http://pastebin.com/4wk5QS43
Controller: http://pastebin.com/5TYwDM8f
Thanks in advance!

Comment: would have been better with a codepen or plunkr. I'll try to see if I found anything

Answer (score 1):

Your process is the following :
- initiate controller : value of Loading = false + getDatas (initiate image)
- if user Swipe, then, getNewDatas

while getting newDatas, your are not "cleaning" your current datas, and, therefore, the image remains the same UNTIL the promise that initiate the image is done.

You have 2 solutions now : 
- or you wait for the promise that initiate the image to be done
- or you clean your datas while "swipe"

If you clean, It's probable that you'll have a small blank image BEFORE the promise is done, therefore, I suggest you to wait for the promise of the image to be done before finishing the loading.

Your solution shall be therefore linked to that function

```
$scope.change_image = function($event){
      angular.element(document.getElementById('main_image')).attr("src", angular.element($event.target).attr('src'));  
  };
```

**Where do you call it ? how ? I coulnd't find any clue in your pastbin**

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're not using the [tinder-cards ion](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-ion-tinder-cards)? It could make your life a bit simpler.

Whether or not you use it, you could directly launch request for two cards' data (and preload images) on app launch, so that when Card1 is swiped, you can directly show Card2 (without having to request any  data), and at the same time launch a request for a third card's data to get ready for the next swipe.